# Change the Default Pages Menu View in wp-admin

Tags: admin, wp-admin, pages, redirect, admin-menu

I can't seem to figure out how to change the default view for *"Pages"* in the admin menu.

The initial view is the *"Pages"* view (`/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page`)

How could it change this to something else?
Like *"Add New Page"*? (`/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page`)

I've tried several different options including rebuilding the menu with a custom menu, but it seems like WordPress automatically keeps redirecting the *"Pages"* view (`/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page`).

Comment: Why would you change the default view? There's already an "Add new page" page. Where would you list the pages then?

Comment: Im actually using a page order plugin that creates a new sub item to re-order pages. That is what I want to be the default page, but I cannot change it to anything. I would then hide the all pages view. Follow me?

Comment: I've created a custom menu that will point here: edit.php?post_type=page&page=custom_page_order but it redirects to the Posts reorder instead of pages.

Answer (score 1):

**[Update]**
*Answer rewritten, based on [this other Q&A](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73006/12615).*

---

To achieve this:

[image: default pages menu view]

Use this code:

```
add_filter( 'custom_menu_order', 'wpse_48933_submenu_order' );

function wpse_48933_submenu_order( $menu_ord ) 
{
    global $submenu;

    // Enable the next line to inspect the $submenu values
    // echo '<pre>'.print_r($submenu,true).'</pre>';

    $arr = array();
    $arr[] = $submenu['edit.php?post_type=page'][10];
    $arr[] = $submenu['edit.php?post_type=page'][5];
    $submenu['edit.php?post_type=page'] = $arr;

    return $menu_ord;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a custom plugin, use this PHP to remove the Pages page.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_custom_pages' );

function my_custom_pages() {
    remove_menu_page('edit.php?post_type=page'); // Pages
            add_menu_page('Pages', 'Pages', 'author', 'pages', 'my_custom_menu_page' );
}

function my_custom_menu_page() {
    // The function to load your new page
}
```

This will need customizing, but it takes care of removing the original and replacing it with yours.

Comment: Ok, so I have a custom Menu, the Parent Menu item is pointing here:edit.php?post_type=page&page=edit.php?post_type=page&page=custom_page_order  But it is redirecting to Post order, not pages. The fist sub menu item has the same exact link:edit.php?post_type=page&page=edit.php?post_type=page&page=custom_page_order It works properly, it goes to the Pages order

Answer (score 0):

A different way of doing this is to add your custom query variable into the loading of the page.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_custom_query_vars' );
function my_custom_query_vars() {
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if ( $screen->id == 'edit-page' ) {
        set_query_var( 'orderby', 'custom_page_order' );
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow how this is supposed to work?