# Re-ordering Admin Submenu Sections

Tags: admin, admin-menu

I was looking at **the method below** to reorder the **Admin Menu Sections**:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1220/1044

...and was wondering if it's possible to reorder the **submenu sections** using similar method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is, but I cannot find a simpler way...

Here, we are changing the `Media` submenu and inverting `Add new` and `Library`.

```
add_filter( 'custom_menu_order', 'wpse_73006_submenu_order' );

function wpse_73006_submenu_order( $menu_ord ) 
{
    global $submenu;

    // Enable the next line to inspect the $submenu values
    // echo '<pre>'.print_r($submenu,true).'</pre>';

    $arr = array();
    $arr[] = $submenu['upload.php'][10];
    $arr[] = $submenu['upload.php'][5];
    $submenu['upload.php'] = $arr;

    return $menu_ord;
}
```